# How to construct $\Delta ABC$ given $a$, height from $A$ on $BC$ and A$B:AC$.

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

How to construct $\Delta ABC$ given $a$, height from $A$ on $BC$ and A$B:AC$.

Comment: I think there are  2,1 or 0 possible triangles you can build with these data

Comment: However, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius is really useful in this case

Answer (score 1):

If the ratio $\frac{AB}{AC}$ is known, then $A$ belong to an [Apollonius circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius) relative to the segment $BC=a$, hence the problem can be solved by intersecting a line parallel to $BC$ with the previous circle. Here it is an explicit solution for $BC=4$, $\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{2}{3}$ and $h_a=3$:

[image]

Comment: Nice link. (+1)